# How to mimic curl REST call with Spring's RestTemplate?

Tags: spring, rest, curl, junit, resttemplate

Have an external Restful Web Service which takes in JSON payloads if its is more than one input but if its a single input it just needs the value.

For example, for multiple inputs, this works:

```
curl -H "Content-Type: application/json" -X POST -d '{ "amount": 10000, "interestRate": ".28", "term": "12", "state": "Georgia"}' http://localhost:8080/webservices/REST/sample/loan
```

Returns:

```
Approved
```

For single inputs:

```
curl -H "Content-Type: application/json" -X POST -d "18" http://localhost:8080/webservices/REST/sample/age
```

Returns:

```
Approved
```

Using Spring Boot, tried to create a JUnit test, in order, to see if I can post to this external service using Spring's RestTemplate API.

```
public void RestWebServiceTest {

    private RestTemplate restTemplate;
    private HttpHeaders headers;

    @Before
    public void setup() {
        restTemplate = new RestTemplate();
        headers = new HttpHeaders();
        headers.setAccept(Arrays.asList(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON));
    }

    @Test
    public void validLoan() {
        final String uri = "http://localhost:8080/webservices/REST/sample/Loan";
        Map<String, String> input = new HashMap<>();
        input.put("amount", "10000");
        input.put("interestRate", ".28");
        input.put("term", "12");
        input.put("state", "Georgia");
        String result = restTemplate.postForObject(uri, input, String.class);
        assertEquals("Approved", result);
    }

    @Test
    public void validAge() {
        final String uri = "http://localhost:8080/webservices/REST/sample/age";
        Integer input = 18;
        String result = restTemplate.postForObject(uri, input, String.class);
        assertEquals("Approved", result);
    }

    @Test
    public void validCountry() {
        final String uri = "http://localhost:8080/webservices/REST/sample/country
        String input = "US";
        String result = restTemplate.postForObject(uri, input, String.class);
        assertEquals("Approved", result);
    }
}
```

All of these work except for the validCountry() test method:

```
org.springframework.web.client.HttpClientErrorException: 415 Unsupported Media Type
    at org.springframework.web.client.DefaultResponseErrorHandler.handleError(DefaultResponseErrorHandler.java:91)
    at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.handleResponse(RestTemplate.java:641)
    at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.doExecute(RestTemplate.java:597)
```

This is strange because this curl command works for the same call:

```
curl -H "Content-Type: application/json" -X POST -d 'US' http://localhost:8080/webservices/REST/sample/country
```

Returns:

```
Approved
```

Question(s):

1. How can one mimic the rest call for the country (see above curl command) inside the validCountry() test method?
2. Do I need to add or change a different value for HTTP Headers (inside setup() method)?
3. Don't understand that validAge works by using the Integer wrapper class but the String doesn't?
4. Is there a better way to do this using Spring's RestTemplate API?

Thank you for taking the time to read this...

Comment: I don't use what RestTemplate, but I would image it's default Content-Type isn't application/json if you are getting a 415. Try explicitly setting the Content-Type header to application/json

Comment: I did do that in the setup() method.

Comment: No you set the `Accept` header. They're two different things

Answer (score 1):

You need to set the Content-Type to application/json. Content-Type has to be set in request. Below is the modified code to set the Content-Type

```
@Test
public void validCountry() {
    final String uri = "http://localhost:8080/webservices/REST/sample/country";
    String input = "US";
    HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
    headers.setContentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON);
    HttpEntity<String> request = new HttpEntity<String>(input, headers);
    String result = restTemplate.postForObject(uri, request, String.class);
    assertEquals("Approved", result);
}
```

Here, HttpEntity is constructed with your input i.e "US" and with headers.

I think this answers you questions 1,2 and 4. But not 3.

Comment: For your 3rd question, I tried here with a simple sample and it worked for String and Integer. Could you please add the error that your are getting when you use String?

Comment: Then please set the Content-Type header and try with String. But I think the REST services that you use are written in a way that it accepts only Integer and not String.